# Are labels relevant when download emails from gmail to sqlserver?

Tags: gmail, pop3

I want to create a local copy of my emails on gmail.

would labels be relevent in this process?
How would I access a specific folder when using POP3?

Answer (score 1):

Via POP3 you can access only INBOX folder. If you want to work with labels try connecting via IMAP protocol. The Gmail labels maps to IMAP mail folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. In the POP3 world, only the INBOX exists. There aren't any other folders.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly enough, I have been researching the net for sometime now. I have been developing a .net windows application which is pretty well (MS Outlook) and at the core of my experiments sits POP3!

It turns out Inbox is not the only folder visible to POP3! For example when I execute a POP3 LIST command down a TCP connection pipe I get a list of emails, which includes the emails sitting in the "sent" folder of Gmail account!
I have no way of differentiating the two folders in my communications but I am searching for one!!

Comment: that's not a complete answer. try bringing results, or leave this as a comment.